# SQL filtering a WHERE field

Tags: sql, vba, coreldraw

Its my first post as I've managed to cope with just reading all the existing discussions to fix any problems or learn anything I'm stumped on. However with this problem has me well and truly stumped!

The company I work at saves individual jobs under a job number, this is currently a six digit 207076 number. Basically what I want to do is take those six digits, search a database for that job and pull in all the details(customer and job info) that I might require. Should be pretty simple. Get the file name then just that as a string to search in the relevant field.

Well not really because each job number in the database starts with 2 or 3 characters that represent the estimators initials. Also the length of the job number started at 1000. To illustrate how the entries please so the screen grab below

[sample of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fAlq.png)

Firstly I tried a sub string and just stripping the first two characters off:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE substring(reference ,3 ,len(reference)) = " & jobno & " AND version = " & ver
```

This only works some times as a few of our estimators have entered their initials with three characters

Secondly I tried using a right command and just comparing with the last 6 digits

```
strSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE Right(reference, 6)  = " & jobno & " AND version = " & ver & " ORDER BY [createdDate]
```

Again only works some of the time as if you hit any job in the database with less than 6 digits in its name it crashes.

My Last idea was to reference the Excel library and use the VAL function but I cant seem to get this to work within the SQL statement. I'm really not sure how to fix the issue.

Coreldraw's VBA seems to be extremely flakey with SQL statements; a lot of the things I've read just don't seem to apply which makes it extremely frustrating for learning. I believe I my [references to be correct?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbIzH.png)

Full code below (passwords and database info blanked out)

All crits and help welcome, 
Thanks

```
Private Function descriptions(ByVal x As Double, y As Double, w As Double, h        As Double, jobno As String, ver As String)
'On Error GoTo ex
ActiveDocument.ReferencePoint = cdrTopLeft
Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim objRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command



Dim strSQL As String, path As String
Dim bol As Boolean
Dim recordsCounter As Long, a As Long, b As Long
Dim fieldvalue As Variant
Dim QR As String
Dim dat As Variant
Dim FULLID As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long


'CONNECT TO SERVER AND DB
'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -


With objConn
            .Provider = "SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxx;"
            .ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;"
    .Open
End With

If objConn.State <> 1 Then MsgBox "You were unable to connect to the database!", vbInformation

'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

strSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE substring(reference ,3 ,len(reference)) = " & jobno & " AND version = " & ver

'strSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE Right(reference, 6)  = " & jobno & " AND version = " & ver & " ORDER BY [createdDate]

'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

objRS.Open strSQL, objConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
QR = objRS.Fields(0).Value
FULLID = objRS.Fields(1).Value
MsgBox FULLID

'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
strSQL = "SELECT [itemId], [quantity], [description] FROM quotationitems WHERE quotationid = " & [QR] & " ORDER BY [itemId];"
'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

objRS.Close
objRS.Open strSQL, objConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic




'RETRIEVE DESCRIPTIONS
'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -


Dim DX As Double, DY As Double, DW As Double, DH As Double
Dim drx As Double, dry As Double, drw As Double, drh As Double
Dim DESCRIP As New ShapeRange
Dim s1 As Shape
Dim descriprange As Shape
Dim DLINE As String

Dim Desc As String, itm As String, quantity As String

DX = x + (w * 0.005)
DY = y + (h * 0.001)

Do While Not objRS.EOF

        If objRS.Fields(0).Value <> -1 Then itm = Chr(64 + objRS.Fields(0).Value)
        If objRS.Fields(1).Value <> -1 Then quantity = objRS.Fields(1)
        If objRS.Fields(2).Value <> -1 Then Desc = objRS.Fields(2)
        DLINE = "ITEM " & replace(itm, vbCr, "  ") & "   Qty:  " & quantity & "   " & Chr(13) & Desc



        Set s1 = ActiveLayer.FindShape("DESCRIPTIONENTRYPOINT")
        s1.Duplicate
        s1.TEXT.Story = DLINE
        s1.TEXT.Story = replace(s1.TEXT.Story, vbCr & vbCr, "")
        s1.TEXT.Story = replace(s1.TEXT.Story, "ITEM ", vbCr & vbCr & "ITEM   ")
        DESCRIP.Add s1
        DY = DY - (s1.SizeHeight * 1.1)
        s1.ObjectData("Name") = "DESCRIPTION-PARAGRAPH"


    recordsCounter = recordsCounter + 1
    objRS.MoveNext

  Loop
  objRS.Close

    Dim TRS As ShapeRange
    Set TRS = ActiveLayer.FindShapes("DESCRIPTIONENTRYPOINT")
    TRS.Delete

'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -


'POSITION + SCALE DESCRIPTION TEXT TO SUIT TEMPLATE
'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

DESCRIP.GetBoundingBox DX, DY, DW, DH, False
DESCRIP.CreateSelection
Set DESCRIP = ActiveSelectionRange.ReverseRange

Set descriprange = ActiveLayer.FindShape("DESCRANGE")
descriprange.GetBoundingBox drx, dry, drw, drh, False


 Dim TXT2 As Shape

 For Each TXT2 In DESCRIP

    TXT2.TEXT.ConvertToParagraph
    TXT2.ObjectData("Name") = "DESCRIPTION-PARAGRAPH"

Next TXT2


DESCRIP.Combine



DESCRIP.SetSize drw, drh
DESCRIP.SetPosition drx, dry + drh


FINE2:



'TIDY GROUPS ADD ADD DESCRIPTION TO TEMPLATE GROUP
'- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Dim FINDTEMP As Shape
Set FINDTEMP = ActivePage.FindShape(name:="template")
Dim regrouped As Shape
Dim regrouper As ShapeRange
Set regrouper = FINDTEMP.UngroupAllEx
DESCRIP.CreateSelection
regrouper.Add ActiveSelection

Set regrouped = regrouper.Group
regrouped.ObjectData("Name") = "template"
regrouper.RemoveAll




Set objCmd = Nothing
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing
ex:
End Function
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to squash up multiple bits of info into one field like this. And now you have 'cemented' this design issue into place by writing a whole bunch of code around it.

Comment: I you assume you are referring to the 'Dline' string where I combine all the fields?  I will try to separate these  and put them on the page in their own entry points. 
I'm still very new to this so a more detailed explanation of anything I'm doing wrong would be very much welcomed. Thanks

Comment: In short, you should not create database keys (i.e. job  number) based on real world things. If you get two people with the same initials, or someone changes their last name, or you get more than 9999 jobs, or job is passed on to someone else, this key fails. Read the part on 'non identifying value' in this link: http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/sql-design-how-choose-primary-key. I understand that it's handy to have a recognisable job number but you must not base your database joins on it and at this stage you should avoid building external logic (i.e. VBA) on it

Comment: You can have an extra identifying column in your table that contains this 'natural key' as an alias but don't base business logic or database joins on it because you'll just have to unwind it all later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Access Databases Wilcards](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1)

**Example 1:**

```
strSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '*" & jobno & "' AND version = " & ver
```

**Example 2:**

```
Const BaseSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '*@jobno' AND version = @ver"
strSQL = Replace(BaseSQL, "@jobno", jobno)
strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@ver", ver)
```

[Sequel Server Wildcards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

**Example 1:**

```
strSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '%" & jobno & "' AND version = " & ver
```

**Example 2:**

```
Const BaseSQL = "SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '%@jobno' AND version = @ver"
strSQL = Replace(BaseSQL, "@jobno", jobno)
strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@ver", ver)
```

Comment: Wow fast reply! Though now I'm getting the message
"Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
Incorrect syntax near '*'.
:(  In the mean time I will research the like function

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print strSQL` and post it in a comment?

Comment: I'm starting to suspect there's something wrong with either coreldraws vba or the reference library Im using.
Is this a thing? I've noticed quite a lot of the functionality for SQL isn't working as intended

Comment: SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like *207076 AND version = 1
I ported my VBA code from corel into Access's VBA and get the same results so maybe my VBA isn't borked afterall?

Comment: You never added the single quotes. `SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '*207076' AND version = 1`

Comment: Oh wow. sorry I swear I copied it. Post your edit to the code! Okay now  my immediate window says:

SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like *207076 AND version = 1

And I get the error message:
Run-time error '3021':

Either BOF or EOF is true, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

Comment: I still don't see the single quotes.  I added another example to my answer.  It's a way of avoiding the complexity of string concatenation.

Comment: Still getting the Run-tme error '3021' hmmm
In the immediate window I get:
    SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '*@jobno' AND version = (AT)ver
    SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '*202713' AND version =( AT)ver
    SELECT [id] FROM quotation WHERE reference Like '*202713' AND version = 1
Changed @ to (AT) since it was giving me an error message for notifying too many people

Comment: Oh The job number and version changed because I am trying it with a job that worked yesterday so I know these details are correct. 
And again really appreciate your efforts for helping me figure this out, I'm still very new to this, so thanks

Comment: I am sorry about the trouble I didn't realize that you are using a Sequel Sever database.  Sequel Server uses **%** instead of the asterisk for a wild card.  I have a link to the Sequel Server wildcards reference in my updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic! This seems to work on every job now! Great stuff Thank you.
:)

Comment: Thanks for the Check Mark!!